# PostgreSQL: import/restore database dump (pg_dump version 9.6.5) on Windows

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, database-restore

I am a newbie and I have a postgresql large dump of type .sql and i want to import it. I am on Windows 10 and haven't been able to find solution.

I tried to restore using pgAdmin3 but it doesn't show .sql file while restoring. I also found few commands and tried them but nothing seems to work.
I also tried loading the datasource in IntelliJ DataGrid but it doesn't show the correct driver during the loading settings.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, figure out if the dump was created with `pg_dumpall` or `pg_dump`.
Dumps from `pg_dumpall` start with:

```
--
-- PostgreSQL database cluster dump
--
```

If the dump was created with `pg_dump`, find out if the `-C` option was used.
If yes, the dump will contain a line with a `CREATE DATABASE` statement.

To restore, use `psql` from the DOS box. I assume that `psql` is on your PATH.

A dump from `pg_dumpall` or `pg_dump -C` is restored with

```sh
psql -U postgres -d postgres -f dumpfile.sql
```

A dump from `pg_dump` without `-C` is restored with

```sh
psql -U postgres -d mydatabase -f dumpfile.sql
```

where `mydatabase` should be replaced with the name of the target database into which the dump should be restored.